# Java Dynamic Web ServletConfig Class Not Found

Tags: java, servlets, weblogic12c, intellij-14, eclipse-oxygen

### Export Intellij Project Folder to Eclipse

I am not very familiar to Java. Currently I was given a IntelliJ project folder but have no access to IntelliJ IDE. How to properly import the project into Eclipse without errors? This application is running on Weblogic Server R12 and is using struts too (not sure if any special configuration needed).

---

### UPDATE

Manage to port to Eclipse with direction from Confused Kangaroo. But it just wont deploy to Oracle Weblogic Server 12.1.2.0. Can someone guide me how to resolve this error? Am I missing some configuration?

```
Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ServletConfig"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ServletConfig
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ServletConfig
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1026)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:987)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:83)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:608)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:540)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to here : [How to convert IntelliJ project to Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781137/how-to-convert-intellij-project-to-eclipse)

Comment: Hi could you guide me on the issue i faced? I have updated in the question.

Comment: You might be missing the servlet api jar in the class path. Try adding the library in your java build path. Java build path -> Add library -> Server run time -> choose your server.